# Scaling sprites in XNA 4.0/Monogame

Tags: xna-4.0, monogame, scale

So I looked up a tutorial on how to scale sprites in XNA and I think I have it all figured out.

The only problem is that I want to use a `spriteBatch.Begin()` method overload without changing anything except for the Matrix.

The only `spriteBatch.Begin()` method that has a Matrix as a parameter is this one:

```
public void Begin (
         SpriteSortMode sortMode,
         BlendState blendState,
         SamplerState samplerState,
         DepthStencilState depthStencilState,
         RasterizerState rasterizerState,
         Effect effect,
         Matrix transformMatrix
)
```

I don't really want to mess around with any of the parameters except to pass in my matrix. How would I do that?

Answer (score 4):

If you simply want to scale a sprite you can do

```
spriteBatch.Begin();
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, null, Color.White, 0f, 
Vector2.Zero, 0.5f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
spriteBatch.End();
```

or

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, null, null, null, 
Matrix.CreateScale(0.5f));
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();
```

Where 0.5f means 50% of the normal size of your texture. You could also use a Vector2(x,y) instead of a float, where the x would be the resize on width, and y the resize on y.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to use a Matrix as a camera and to scale and rotate the scene then spriteBatch.Begin() is indeed what you are looking for. Now I know it looks like a lot of parameters but you can actually assign most of them null values. For example:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, null, null, null, null, YourMatrix);
```

You can find out what the SpriteSortModes do [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritesortmode.aspx), but Deferred is usually what you'll want. It's really worth it to familiarize yourself with the other parameters though and you can find them on the MSDN docs as well.